# file.path function doesn't find files

Tags: r

I have a code that looks for certain files inside a folder according to my samples file.

```
reads <- dir(path = file.path(reads_folder, samples$SAMPLE_ID), 
             pattern = "fastq.gz$", full.names = TRUE)
```

The code works great when I have the following structure: **reads_folder/SAMPLE_ID01/SAMPLE_ID_01.fastq.gz**.

But I want to change my file structure and leave it in only one folder, for example, **reads_folder/SAMPLE_ID_01.fastq.gz**.
That way the same code does not work, because it expects the SAMPLE_ID to be a folder.

Would anyone know how to do this so that the files fetched are just the ones I have in my samples file?

Comment: If there is a clear pattern for `SAMPLE_ID` that can be generalized easily, then perhaps. If not, since `pattern=` only accepts a single regex, you'll need to combine multiple calls to `dir` to find the multiple patterns. Or you can use `dir(path=reads_folder, pattern="fastq.gz$", ...)` and filter them out by `samples$SAMPLE_ID` after the fact. I can't really help much more without seeing samples of the data. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55666535/edit) your question and add the output from `dput(head(samples))`?

Comment: I just changed the code to 
`reads <- dir(path=file.path(reads_folder), pattern = "fastq.gz$", full.names = TRUE)`. Now I can find all the files in the reads_folder, but I can't control by the samples file which files I want to.

Comment: (1) `file.path(reads_folder)` is unnecessary here, just use `reads_folder`. (2) I'll try to help more based on the contents of `samples`; if you need more help please provide the output from `dput(head(samples))`.

Comment: > `dput(head(samples))` 

structure(list(SAMPLE_ID = c("SAMPLE01", "SAMPLE02", "SAMPLE03"
), Read_1 = c("SAMPLE01_Escherichia_E.Coli_R1_001.fastq.gz", 
"SAMPLE02_Escherichia_E.Coli_R1_001.fastq.gz", "SAMPLE03_Escherichia_E.Coli_R1_001.fastq.gz"
), Read_2 = c("SAMPLE01_Escherichia_E.Coli_R2_001.fastq.gz", 
"SAMPLE02_Escherichia_E.Coli_R2_001.fastq.gz", "SAMPLE03_Escherichia_E.Coli_R2_001.fastq.gz"
)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: Haniel, extensive code/data typically do very poorly in comments; additionally, comments are easily skipped by follow-on readers, either oversight or because comments can be intentionally "folded" to hide when there are many other comments. Because of that, and to keep the question itself fully reproducible, I suggest you put data like that into your question by editing it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reach files in multiple subfolders, you can set the argument `recursive = TRUE`. Also to get a multiple pattern of sample, you can gather the values using `paste`.

```
multiple_samples <- paste0(samples$SAMPLE_ID, collapse = "|")
multiple_samples <- paste0("(", multiple_samples, ")+")

reads <- dir(path = reads_folder, 
             pattern = paste0(multiple_samples, ".*\\.fastq.gz$"), 
             full.names = TRUE, 
             recursive = TRUE)
```

Comment: In multiple subfolder this code `reads <- dir (path = file.path(reads_folder, samples$SAMPLE_ID), pattern = "fastq.gz$", full.names = TRUE)` works fine. My problem is when I don't have subfolders. Just the read_folders/files.fastq.gz

Comment: Ok, But the didn't the code work for this case too ?

Comment: No. Just work for subfolders. I changed the code to `reads <- dir(path=file.path(reads_folder), pattern = "fastq.gz$", full.names = TRUE)`  and works fine, but I can't control by the samples file which files I want to

Comment: You have to use the variable `multiple_samples` that I put in the code, try that.

Comment: Didn't work.
Results from my code `> reads <- dir (path = reads_folder, pattern = "fastq.gz$", recursive = FALSE, all.files = TRUE, include.dirs = FALSE, full.names = TRUE)
> reads
[1] "00-Fastq/SAMPLE01_Escherichia_E.Coli_R1_001.fastq.gz" "00-Fastq/SAMPLE01_Escherichia_E.Coli_R2_001.fastq.gz"
[3] "00-Fastq/SAMPLE02_Escherichia_E.Coli_R1_001.fastq.gz" "00-Fastq/SAMPLE02_Escherichia_E.Coli_R2_001.fastq.gz"
[5] "00-Fastq/SAMPLE03_Escherichia_E.Coli_R1_001.fastq.gz" "00-Fastq/SAMPLE03_Escherichia_E.Coli_R2_001.fastq.gz"`

Comment: Results from your code: 
`> reads <- dir(path = reads_folder, 
+              pattern = paste0(multiple_samples, "\\.fastq.gz$"), 
+              full.names = TRUE, 
+              recursive = TRUE)
> reads
character(0)`

Comment: It seems that have to update the regex to attempt your paths. I have updated the answer, you can check it again.

Comment: I changed your code to use only one variable.

`reads <- dir(path = reads_folder, 
             pattern = paste0("(", samples$SAMPLE_ID, ")+", collapse = "|", ".*\\.fastq.gz$"), 
             full.names = TRUE, 
             recursive = TRUE)`

Comment: Nice it worked, please consider mark this solution as the answer.